# Why does Twitter OAuth reject request token request with message "The given URL is considered malware"?

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4J, and when I request an OAuth request token, an exception is thrown with the following message:

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <error>The given URL is considered malware</error>
  <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
</hash>

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=8e063946 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ef59cf90
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[8e063946-ef59cf90], statusCode=401, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.1}
```

The question [In getting request token flow of OAuth, I've received "The given URL is considered malware"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846760/in-getting-request-token-flow-of-oauth-ive-received-the-given-url-is-consider) appears relevant, but it was closed as "not a real question" and the accepted answer, that my third-party app has been flagged as malware, does not apply to my case. (I have other web apps that allow users to authorize this same third-party app -- same consumer key/secret -- to access their data without getting this error.)

The only thing I could think of is that the callback URL I include in the request for a token is `http://localhost:8084/authorize/complete/twitter`, and I've never used that callback URL before. But my searches do not reveal restrictions on using localhost or any particular port in a callback URL, and I have a placeholder in the third-party app's Callback URL setting (i.e. the app is not restricted from using callbacks).

What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Ugh, I went to add my request code to the question and I realized that I was providing the callback URL `http://localhost::8084/authorize/complete/twitter` -- note the redundant second colon before the port. Removing it resolved this issue. If anyone knows why that kind of malformed URL gets interpreted as possible malware, I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment on the question, the cause was a typo in the callback URL I was providing in the request. The URL I was providing was

```
http://localhost::8084/authorize/complete/twitter
```

with an accidental second colon before the port. My bad.