# Twitter API treating URL as Malware

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to implement Twitter's Three-legged OAuth flow, but have started to get an exception back from Twitter when running the first stage of the OAuth process, see below

#### The Code

```py
import urllib.parse
from typing import NamedTuple
import oauth2 as oauth

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = ""
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"


class TempToken(NamedTuple):
    oauth_token: str
    oauth_token_secret: str
    oauth_callback_confirmed: bool


def get_temp_token(c: oauth.Client, encoding: str = "utf-8") -> TempToken:
    """
    Step 1: Get a request token. This is a temporary token that is used for
    having the user authorize an access token and to sign the request to obtain
    said access token.

    :param c: oauth Client
    :param encoding: "utf-8"
    :return: TempToken
    """
    resp, content = c.request(TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, "GET")
    if resp.status != 200:
        raise Exception(f"Invalid response {resp['reason']}")

    return TempToken(
        **dict(
            urllib.parse.parse_qsl(
                content.decode(encoding)
            )
        )
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer)
    temp_token = get_temp_token(client)
    print(temp_token)
```

#### The Problem

The line:

```py
resp, content = c.request(TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, "GET")
```

Now results in:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="69">The given URL is considered malware</error></errors>
```

I am unsure why this is happening as yesterday everything was working perfectly.

Comment: Similar [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15849153/5320906), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281205/5320906).